# How to increase bufsize in importdata

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I have a CSV file that I want to import in MATLAB as a vector, but when I use MATLAB's `importdata`. It says:

```
Buffer overflow (bufsize = 1000005) while reading string from file
```

It's because there is more that 1000005 numbers in my file, how can I increase the `bufsize` so that I can import this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look around line 315 of importdata.m (R2014a):

```
%Arbitrarily set the maximum size for a line, used to calculate this but it
%was slow, so we went with all in one line or the old maximum it would
%check.
bufsize = min(1000000, max(numel(fileString),100)) + 5;
```

That's clearly where the 1000005 is coming from.

I'd say to just edit this line with value larger than the current 1,000,000.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the [**`InputBufferSize`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/inputbuffersize.html) to increase the buffer size.

Alternatively, to import large data files, consider to **read the file in segments**, which reduces the amount of memory required. Check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-large-text-files.html) for examples.

Comment: How can I configure InputBufferSize? It doesn't say anything about configuring it in the link

Comment: @Navid777 You can check out this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/instrument/code-examples.html?file=/products/demos/instrument/instrument_properties.html#8).